# Set directory structure in archetype-metadata.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-archetype

I am creating maven-archetype for my project. I have a log4j.properties file in folder "archetype-resources", I want it to be under my project's "src/main/resources/" when I will use this archetype to create maven project. It does not add anything in resources folder if I have xml set like below:

archetype-metadata.xml

```
<fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/log4j.properties</include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

While it works fine and add log4j.properties to root folder when I have

```
<fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
    <directory></directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/log4j.properties</include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following and it should work.

```
<fileSet filtered="true">
  <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
</fileSet>
```